# MongoDB Error: connect EINVAL 0.0.0.123:27017 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Whenever I am trying to run the server this error comes, quite search a little bit  but not able to find the solution.

Server is running fine

```
MongoDB Error:  { Error: connect EINVAL 0.0.0.123:27017 - Local
(0.0.0.0:0) at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11) at 
_exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20) at internalConnect (net.js:960:16) at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope
(internal/async_hooks.js:284:19) at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as
callback] (net.js:1106:9) at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as
oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10) name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect
EINVAL 0.0.0.123:27017 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)' }
```

Here the [error](https://pastebin.com/nmKejD77) if you need it

how to get rid of this, thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never seen an IP address starting with `0.0.0`. Please ensure that you're 1. connecting to the correct IP address and 2. your MongoDB config has `bindIp` set to the correct value. If you're running your application and database on the same server, then your config should be fine and you would be connecting using the `localhost` interface, e.g. `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 3):

This error tends to show up when you aren't prefixing your connection string with the correct protocol, *mongodb*.

From the documentation:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

[mongo connection string documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

So if you are connecting to local host:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```